# Different results when detecting facial landmarks in a single image and in a for loop including the single image with Mediapipe

Tags: python

I'm using Mediapipe with Python to detect facial landmarks in a dataset of images of faces. Here's my issue. When I use Mediapipe on a single image of my dataset, it detects some coordinates, but when I do the same thing in a loop, iterating the code on every image of my dataset, the single image I mentioned above gets different coordinates as a result. I'm using the exact same line of codes for the single image and the loop to perform facial landmarks detection.
Does someone have an explanation as to why this is happening?

Comment: Does it use random starts? If so you have to set the seed each time for reproducibility. I do not use Python or Mediapipe so this is a pure guess.